# Spring Integration(MQTT): Retrieving published message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mqtt

I am new to spring boot and am trying to use the sample example from the spring integration in order to subscribe and publish using MQTT. I manage to integrate it with Thingsboard and the logger in the code below is able to receive the published message from Thingsboard.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MqttTest.class);
}

@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "URI HERE" });
    options.setUserName("ACCESS TOKEN HERE");
    factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
    return factory;
}

// consumer

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .transform(p -> p)
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}

private LoggingHandler logger() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("LoggerBot");
    return loggingHandler;
}

@Bean
public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("Consumer",
            mqttClientFactory(), "v1/devices/me/rpc/request/+");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    return adapter;
}
```

This is the console output. I am able to receive the published json message that was sent from the thingsboard dashboard. I am wondering if there is a call method to retrieve the json message string so that I can process it further. Thank you.

```
2019-02-01 14:06:23.590  INFO 13416 --- [ Call: Consumer] LoggerBot : {"method":"setValue","params":true}
2019-02-01 14:06:24.840  INFO 13416 --- [ Call: Consumer] LoggerBot : {"method":"setValue","params":false}
```

Comment: Do you want to handle the message after logging ?. Then simply chain another handler ```.handle( (message) -> { handle here }```.

Comment: Hi @Barath, my intention is to get the params value from the json message and process it further in another class to some other functions

Comment: There are lot of ways in doing it. If you only want to consume the message, use [MessageHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-handle) and chain it with integration flow or you could use service activator. Let us know if you need any help.

Comment: @Barath im quite new to spring boot so i would appreciate some help here. Lets say i would like to pass the message into a method that I have created e.g. extractParamValue(String message) that extracts the json value of "params" key

Comment: Lets continue in this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187709/54474014-discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the published messages, subscribe message handles to the flow to consume the messages.

**MessageHandler**

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
                .transform(p -> p)
                .handle( mess -> {
                   System.out.println("mess"+mess);
                 })            
                .get();
    }
```

**ServiceActivator**

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
                .transform(p -> p)
                .handle("myService","handleHere")
                .handle(logger())
                .get();
    }

@Component
public class MyService {

    @ServiceActivator
    public Object handleHere(@Payload Object mess) {
        System.out.println("payload "+mess);
        return mess;
    }
}
```

Note: As we discussed, there are lot of different ways of achieving it.
This is just a sample for your understanding.

Comment: Clear and simple. Thanks.